# Eclipse CDT indexing files in /usr/local/include

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Indigo with CDT 8.0.2 to browse through the code of a C++ library. The library is also installed on my system. Many times when I go to a declaration of a function, Eclipse finds the declaration in a file under `/usr/local/include`, even though the header file is also in the project.

Can I avoid this behavior? For now I'd be okay with limiting the indexer to index only files within the project. In the Indexer Preferences, I unchecked `Index source files not included in the build` without success.

Answer (score 1):

So I just came across this because I am having a similar problem 11 years after the original post. I found what may be the answer, so perhaps this will help the next person who comes across this thread.

Check if your project's property under C/C++ General/Preprocessor Include Paths has an entry for /usr/local/include. You could remove it to see if that does what you need.